# How can I get my columns to align vertically with multicols?

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, multicol

For some reason there's this ugly blank line in the left column that I just can;t get rid of. Here's what Ive got typed out:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\(y_{1}(t)\):
\noindent
\begin{align*}
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{1}''-2y_{1}\\
    &=t^2(2)-2t^{2}\\
    &=2t^{2}-2t^{2}\\
    &=0
\end{align*}

\columnbreak

\(y_{2}(t)\):
\begin{align*}
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{2}''-2y_{2}\\
    &=t^{2}\left(\frac{2}{t^3}\right)-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=\frac{2}{t}-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=0
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}
```

What could I do to fix it? I've never really run into this issue before

Comment: You have placed `\noindent` just before a math display environment.  That has the effect of starting a new paragraph, but the display math then starts a new "block", leaving a blank line.  If you want the display block flush left, use `flalign` as the environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an approach similar to the one you're using now, I would use `\raggedcolumns` so that the `multicols` environment doesn't try to vertically balance the shorter material in the left column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns
\noindent\(y_{1}(t)\):
\begin{align*}
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{1}''-2y_{1}\\
    &=t^2(2)-2t^{2}\\
    &=2t^{2}-2t^{2}\\
    &=0
\end{align*}

\columnbreak

\noindent\(y_{2}(t)\):
\begin{align*}
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{2}''-2y_{2}\\
    &=t^{2}\left(\frac{2}{t^3}\right)-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=\frac{2}{t}-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=0
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: multicol with raggedcolumns]

However, in this case, I'm not sure why you need columns for this at all. If your equations don't need to be separately numbered, you can use a single `align*` environment, as this environment supports multiple sets of aligned formulas next to each other.

Alternatively, you could put each group inside an `aligned` environment; then the larger spacing (because of the fractions) in the right group won't be applied to the left group as well.

Here's code for both approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}

With one big align environment:

\begin{align*}
& \mathrlap{y_{1}(t):} & & & & \mathrlap{y_{2}(t):} & & & \\
& &    t^2 y''-2y &=t^2 y_{1}''-2y_{1} &&& t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{2}''-2y_{2}             \\
& &               &=t^2(2)-2t^{2}      &&&           &=t^{2}\left(\frac{2}{t^3}\right)-\frac{2}{t} \\
& &               &=2t^{2}-2t^{2}      &&&           &=\frac{2}{t}-\frac{2}{t} \\
& &               &=0                  &&&           &=0
\end{align*}

With two aligned environments inside an align* environment:

\begin{align*}
y_{1}(t): & & y_{2}(t): \\
%
& \begin{aligned}[t]
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{1}''-2y_{1}\\
    &=t^2(2)-2t^{2}\\
    &=2t^{2}-2t^{2}\\
    &=0
\end{aligned}
&
&
\begin{aligned}[t]
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{2}''-2y_{2}\\
    &=t^{2}\left(\frac{2}{t^3}\right)-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=\frac{2}{t}-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: align* environments]

Answer (score 2):

You needn't `multicol` package. You can construct the same by TeX primitive `\hbox` and two `\vtop`s inside it:

```
\hbox to\hsize{%
   \vtop{smaller \hsize, left material}\hss
   \vtop{smaller \hsize, right material}}
```

Your example looks like this:

```
\hbox to\hsize{%
\vtop{\hsize=.45\hsize
\(y_{1}(t)\):
\begin{align*}
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{1}''-2y_{1}\\
    &=t^2(2)-2t^{2}\\
    &=2t^{2}-2t^{2}\\
    &=0
\end{align*}
}\hss
\vtop{\hsize=.45\hsize
\(y_{2}(t)\):
\begin{align*}
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{2}''-2y_{2}\\
    &=t^{2}\left(\frac{2}{t^3}\right)-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=\frac{2}{t}-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=0
\end{align*}
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may insert your equation systems in table, for example `tblr` defined in the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tblr}{colsep =0pt, 
             colspec={X[c, mode=math] c  X[c, mode=math]}, 
             row{1} ={l}
             }
y_{1}(t):       &\qquad &   y_{2}(t):           \\
%
\begin{aligned}[t]  % <---
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{1}''-2y_{1}\\
    &=t^2(2)-2t^{2}\\
    &=2t^{2}-2t^{2}\\
    &=0
\end{aligned}   &       &  \begin{aligned}[t]˛ % <---
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{2}''-2y_{2}\\
    &=t^{2}\left(\frac{2}{t^3}\right)-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=\frac{2}{t}-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=0
\end{aligned}
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd use two minipages, so you can better control the horizontal and vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some text before the display, long enough to wrap across lines.
Perhaps this is enough.
\[
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\displaywidth}
\(\begin{aligned}[t]
&y_{1}(t)\,{:}\\
&\quad
  \begin{aligned}
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{1}''-2y_{1}\\
    &=t^2(2)-2t^{2}\\
    &=2t^{2}-2t^{2}\\
    &=0
  \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\)
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\displaywidth}
\(\begin{aligned}[t]
&y_{2}(t)\,{:} \\
&\quad
  \begin{aligned}
    t^2 y''-2y&=t^2 y_{2}''-2y_{2}\\
    &=t^{2}\left(\frac{2}{t^3}\right)-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=\frac{2}{t}-\frac{2}{t}\\
    &=0
  \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\)
\end{minipage}
\]
Some text below the display, long enough to wrap across lines.
Perhaps this is enough.

\end{document}
```

[image]